# ui-route how to render multi ui-view when route to template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

my requirement is:

```
index.html  
   -- /login  
   -- /main/tab1
   -- /main/tab2
   -- /userinfo
```

And the ui will be like:

- header: logo, userinfo
- left-nav: switch tab1/tab2/tabN
- right content: ui-view to change, and multi sub ui-view,

And UI detail:

- login will be a independent page, no header, left-nav, right content
- main/tab will only change the right content
- /userinfo will replace the left-nav and right content to some userinfo page, remain the header, of course using ui-view

I've seen the ui-route demo, but follow the demo, I don't know how to build the route config to what I want, so could any one help me ? The ui-route config is a little complex.....
If my url define is not perfect, please help me improve the url structure, thanks

[image]

Comment: Well, The demo and its state def are incomparably the best among any other libraries/documentations. You really should get through yourself, and come back with particullar issues, not with "do that for me"... I'd say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have seen the demo and understood it, this should make sense:

```
.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: //your index.html template path,
    controller: // your controller if any for index page
  })

  .state('index.login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: // your login template,
      controller: // controller for login page
  })

    .state('index.mainTab1', {
        url: '/main/tab1',
        templateUrl: // your tab1 template,
    })
```

add the other states in the same manner and you should be ready to go.